# Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt

What is the best way to connect a device with a Thunderbolt 3 (USB Type-C) port to a computer (MacBook Pro) with a Thunderbolt 2 port?

I understand there will not be full 40 Gbps speed.

Device is a [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B01BL0CKIM/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_D1BFxb33TZ5ZM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01BL0CKIM)

Comment: What make and model and type of device?

Comment: Not exactly sure what I'm going to order yet. I'm looking at this to see if it's even possible first, or whether I have to look in another direction.

Comment: Since there is no Apple hardware or software, this is strictly off-topic for the site, but let's indulge ourselves a bit and see if someone wants to find the thunderbolt specification that explains how you cannot just plug thunderbolt 3 physically into thunderbolt 2 due to pinout and physical size mismatches.

Comment: @bmike the apple hardware would be the MacBook Pro, and I'm fully aware that the plugs are different. This is why I would like to know if an adapter exists. And the device on the other end is https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01BL0CKIM/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_D1BFxb33TZ5ZM

Comment: A friend of mine has it and loves it. So I'd like to use it if I can. But if its not possible I'll look into other options

Comment: That's an awesome unit - edit those details into the post, please : - )

Comment: My reason for needing something like this is that I want to get a T3 dock so that I don't need to upgrade it a few years from now when I get a USB-C/T3 MacBook (Pro), but my current computer only has T2. Really hoping this adapter exists, but I haven't found *anything* so far.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really many alternatives on the market. USB-C to Mini DisplayPort exists, but not many with Thunderbolt 3/2 support.

Apple makes a [Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter?) which is supposed to be bidirectional (read more in [this support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207266)). In that case you would probably need a Thunderbolt 2 male-to-male cable, but it should work in theory.

Comment: It sais: 
```The Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter doesn't support connections to these devices: [...]
MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2015) and later```

Comment: @cocoseis Yes, I suppose that means it doesn't support 12-inch MacBooks. Should still work for MB Pro or Air I believe.

Answer (score 0):

All day long I was looking for the same Thunderbold 3 to Thunderbold 2 adapter in order to be able to connect my new USB Type-C Devices to my "old" MacBook Pro. Meaning something like the inverse of:
https://www.amazon.de/Apple-MMEL2ZM-A-Thunderbolt-Adapter/dp/B01M72VEQR/ref=pd_sbs_147_17?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=3WQZ4QYVZ7BBWCF73R4X

The only thing I could find matching my needs:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Adapter-Maxhood-Macbook-ChromeBook-CFM-3-0M/dp/B01BYG75WY/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1487262986&sr=8-2&keywords=usbc+female 
in addition to:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/KANEX-Thunderbolt-eSATA-USB-Adapter/dp/B00LOLBBQQ%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q%26tag%3Dduckduckgo-osx-uk-21%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB00LOLBBQQ

To me, if I am not missing anything, this looks like there can be a solution. At least from the technical side.